# Is it assur to play sports with a yarmulke?

Tags: halacha, kippa-yarmulka, sport-athletics

Wearing a yarmulke is a minhag. Not putting a stumbling block is d'oreisa.

Yet, I have noticed that Torah observant boys and young men play sports like basketball, flag football, and soccer with yarmulkes, even though there is a very good chance that they will fall off and cause someone to trip.

Is it assur to play sports with a yarmulke?

Comment: not according to the Taz 8:3

Comment: Under circumstances where it would be dangerous to play sports while wearing a yarmulke, i.e. where it is likely to fall and trip someone, it's obvious that one may not do so. However, this doesn't generally seem like a realistic scenario.

Comment: puting aside the discussion of whether there is _"a very good chance that they will fall off and cause someone to trip"_, there is also a discussion whether the prohibition of placing a stumbling block is actually referring to a physical stumbling block, see here (and linked questions): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16772/did-people-ever-place-actual-physical-stumbling-blocks-before-the-blind

Comment: @Fred: "it's obvious one may not do so". Play sports or wear the Yarmulke?

Comment: @GershonGold It's obvious that one may not do anything if you accept the premise that it is dangerous to oneself or others. I don't accept the premise, but it was built into the question. (I was not trying to say that playing sports without a yarmulke would be an acceptable alternative; I wasn't commenting on that point whatsoever).

Comment: ...that's what the bobby pins are for....

Comment: Don't we have something around here about its not being literal?

Comment: I don't think the danger of tripping over someone's yarmulke is the biggest danger athletes face...

Comment: The same could be asked about tzitzs it is too hot(dehydration) wear while playing sports so one should be able to take it off.i don't think it is a vaild argument.

Comment: @SethJ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29561

Comment: @msh210, and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16772/5. Y"K.

Comment: Why did this question get downvotes?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein - I didn't downvote it, but I conjecture that it was downvoted because it *assumed* something should be assur instead of *asking.*

Comment: That's a good point @ShmuelL.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Many who play attach their Yarmulkas via a bobby pin or [Kippon](http://www.jewishsource.com/itemdy00.asp?T1=90837). This assures that it will remain on their head and not fall off while playing sports.

Comment: +1. A good idea, though they are not effective for all types of hair under all circumstances.

Comment: "assures" more likely "mitigates the risk"