# Is it "Lifnei Iver" if someone LITERALLY puts a stumbling block in front of a blind person?

Tags: halacha, lifnei-iver

We generally understand "*Lifnei Iver*" figuratively, like knowingly giving someone bad business advice, or knowingly serving someone non-Kosher food that they were unaware of.

But what about "*Lifnei Iver*" *mamash*? Obviously a terrible thing to do and likely will be *over* other *aveiros*, but would a person violate "*Lifnei Iver*" if they literally put a stumbling block in front of a blind person?

Comment: Thanks for bringing additional valuable attention to this question!