# Is "Though shall not put a stumbling block before the blind" solely metaphorical?

Tags: see-sight-vision-blind, lifnei-iver

There are [blind people who insist on competing in hurdle events](https://youtu.be/qD-3MV3QFBc?feature=shared).

We know from the laws of interest that the deal can be forbidden even if both parties agree.

Is it similarly forbidden to set up the hurdles for him?

Comment: What does agreeing to interest have to do with stumbling blocks?

Comment: That even if the blind person agrees to the stumbling block, it could still be forbidden.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16772/did-people-ever-place-actual-physical-stumbling-blocks-before-the-blind?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest it's not a stumbling block if the purpose is to improve their skills, just like a teacher is allowed mislead his students to test them ([S"A Yoreh Deah 246:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.246.12)):

> ויש לרב להטעות את התלמידים בשאלותיו ובמעשים שעושה לפניהם כדי לחדדם וכדי שידע אם הם זוכרים מה שלומדים

Answer (score 1):

The Kli Yakar on the Posuk (Vayikra 19:14) says ״כי אין לפרש עור ממש ומכשול ממש שהרי נאמר ויראת מאלהיך וזה מדבר בדבר המסור ללב דווקא״. Translated, “don’t explain it to mean an actual blind person and a physical stumbling block, as the posuk continues and says ‘and you shall fear your God’ and this speaks to something that is dependent on one’s heart specifically”. Meaning, something that is dependent on one’s intent in their heart and not something that is able to be seen and others have no insight into.

However, The Kitzur Ba’al Haturim writes ״לא תתן מכשל: חסר וי"ו לומר אפילו אינו נותן מכשול ממש אלא אפילו יועצו לפי דרכו״ which translates to “the word Michshol is missing a letter Vov, this comes to teach that EVEN if it is not a physical stumbling block rather bad advice is also included”

There are many more meforshim who talk about this as well. Some including the literal translation in the meaning, others explaining it to mean specifically pertaining to bad advice.